# .htaccess doesnt take the rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a problem with the htaccess file from a system which i bought.

The Original File looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

My modified version looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^city-([^/]+).html searcharea?city=$1&sd=ls [L]
RewriteRule ^city-normal-([^/]+).html searcharea?city=$1&sd=pb [L]
RewriteRule ^city-special-([^/]+).html searcharea?city=$1&sd=oeb [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The Systems Base Home Link looks like this:

```
http://www.url.de/store/home
```

and my .htaccess is completely ignored, i wonder why?
i want to include  a seo linking to the system and reffer its url to the function but it doesnt work with this htaccess.

i have this htaccess rules in my other htaccess file from another system and there it works perfectly.

### edit:

the rules from original file work, just my rules are ignored. mod_rewrite is enabled

Structure of my dirs:

```
/
/.htaccess
/index.php -> uses yiiframework to build pages
/core
/core/css
/core/js
```

Comment: Please provide some sample URLs you expect to be matched by your new RewriteRule patterns.

Comment: http://www.url.de/city-newyork.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because your orignal htaccess rules are conflicting with the new rules and they rewrite all non existent requests to index.php. To fix this, you need to reorder your rules .

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^city-([^/]+).html searcharea?city=$1&sd=ls [L]
RewriteRule ^city-normal-([^/]+).html searcharea?city=$1&sd=pb [L]
RewriteRule ^city-special-([^/]+).html searcharea?city=$1&sd=oeb [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: i tried this with any order, and i set the destination to index.php to test if i come to index..., but it wont work

Comment: @Jayjay what url are you testing and where is your htaccess located?

Comment: im testing it on 
http://example.com/city-berlin.html

the .htaccess is in root of the domain folder where index.php is also.

my .htaccess looks at moment like this: 


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^city-([^/]+).html /index.php?$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

Comment: i often work with htaccess but never had those issues. its placed in the right folder, it has something to do with the rules and the conds i think, im not that perfect in .htaccess

Comment: @Jayjay RewriteRule is fine. I have tested this on my server. **/city-foobar.html** correctly gets rewritten to **/searcharea?** . . Can you post the structure of your dirs?

Comment: for me it works also on another .htaccess file, but not on this one. the other htaccess has no conditions if its no file or no directory then go forward to index.

but if i place my rule in front, it should work, and it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in apache on your server.

Comment: It is activated, as the rules before work, just my added rules are not working